# Accessing parent data context in meteor templates

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I access parent template's data in Meteor. In below example I want to access `<template name="post">` template data from `<template name="photoGallery">` This is what I am doing but it does not work:

```
<template name="post">
  <div class="well">

    <p class="text-left text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <i>{{post.date}}</i></p>

    <div class="post-text">
      <p>{{post.text}}</p>       
    </div>

    <div class="photo-gallery">
      {{> photoGallery}}
    </div>

    <hr>
    <div class="like-post text-right">
      <button>        
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart liked"></span>
        {{post.likeCount}}
      </button>      
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

and:

```
<template name="photoGallery">
  {{#each post.photos}}  
    <img src="{{src}}"> //this does not work
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

This is my js file for post template:

```
Template.post.helpers({  


    post: {
        text: 'Teks, surat, audio we video. Postda tekst bolanda test uchin ulanyljak yazgy. Shu yazgynyn maksimum simwol sany yuz kyrk simwoldan gechmeli dal. Eger gechen yagdayynda onda kop nokatlar goyulmaly.',
        date: '31-12-205 23:59',
        likeCount: 13,
        photos: [      
          {
            src: 'http://cs625423.vk.me/v625423655/899b/W9agrD2UimQ.jpg',
            src_small: 'http://cs625423.vk.me/v625423655/899a/zkipjxINKM8.jpg',
            src_big: 'http://cs625423.vk.me/v625423655/899c/uL2EOORDYV4.jpg'        
          },
          {
            src: 'http://cs625423.vk.me/v625423655/899b/W9agrD2UimQ.jpg',
            src_small: 'http://cs625423.vk.me/v625423655/899c/uL2EOORDYV4.jpg',
            src_big: 'http://cs625423.vk.me/v625423655/899a/zkipjxINKM8.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: 'http://cs623220.vk.me/v623220655/1e3be/uj7M9HwtkbA.jpg',
            src_small: 'http://cs623220.vk.me/v623220655/1e3bd/hkoSv-zpb4Y.jpg',
            src_big: 'http://cs623220.vk.me/v623220655/1e3bf/Zb3sQa0aX0U.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: 'http://cs623216.vk.me/v623216655/16c18/3mXm6-EZ-aM.jpg',
            src_small: 'http://cs623216.vk.me/v623216655/16c17/RtKyVS-D7GA.jpg',
            src_big: 'http://cs623216.vk.me/v623216655/16c19/_jy0aZu2GEA.jpg'
          }
        ],
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired outcome is for the child template to access a result of the parent's helper. You can do this by setting the context of the `photoGallery` template like so:

```
{{> photoGallery post}}
```

Now, inside of `photoGallery`, the context is a `post` so we can iterate over the photos:

```
<template name="photoGallery">
  {{#each photos}}
    <img src="{{src}}">
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [parentData](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata) is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to solve my problem. I just passed post.photos variable to child template.
In `<template name="post">`:

```
...
<div class="photo-gallery">
  {{> photoGallery photos=post.photos}}
</div>
...
```

And in `<template name="photoGallery">`:

```
{{#each photos}}
  <img src="{{src}}">
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access parent data with ../

`<template name="photoGallery">
  {{#each ../post.photos}}
    <img src="{{src}}">
  {{/each}}
</template>`

If it does not work, you can try:

```
<div class="photo-gallery">
  {{#with post}}
    {{> photoGallery}}
  {{/with}}
</div>
```

and your photo gallery template will look like:

`<template name="photoGallery">
  {{#each this.photos}}
    <img src="{{src}}">
  {{/each}}
</template>`

If you use `#with` helper, photoGallery template will get `post` context and you can use post attributes via `this`.

Comment: The `../` trick works to access the parent's data context but no the result of its helpers.